# Why can't I see my log messages for my actors for levels other than error

Tags: scala, logging, akka

So I have a play application with sub-modules like this:

```
/app  // play app
/modules/notifications
```

Inside my play app I have a task module that starts up my main actor:

```
Logger.debug("starting main supervisor actor Iot")
val supervisor = system.actorOf(IotSupervisor.props(), "iot-supervisor")
```

inside of notifications I have this file:

**/modules/notifications/src/main/supervisor.scala**

```
package com.example.notifications


import akka.actor.{ Actor, ActorLogging, Props }

object IotSupervisor {
  def props(): Props = Props(new IotSupervisor)
}

class IotSupervisor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  log.debug("Iot constrcutor called..")
  override def preStart(): Unit = log.info("IoT Application started")
  override def postStop(): Unit = log.info("IoT Application stopped")

  // No need to handle any messages
  override def receive = Actor.emptyBehavior

}
```

I can see logs in my console:

> [debug] application - starting main supervisor actor Iot [info]
>   p.a.h.EnabledFilters - Enabled Filters (see
>   https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Filters):
>
> ```
> play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter
> play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter
> ```
>
> [info] play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)

My logback.xml looks like:

```
<!-- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/SettingsLogger -->
<configuration>

  <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.libs.logback.ColoredLevel" />

  <!--<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">-->
    <!--<file>${application.home:-.}/logs/application.log</file>-->
    <!--<encoder>-->
      <!--<pattern>%date [%level] from %logger in %thread - %message%n%xException</pattern>-->
    <!--</encoder>-->
  <!--</appender>-->

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{10}</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <!--<appender name="ASYNCFILE" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">-->
    <!--<appender-ref ref="FILE" />-->
  <!--</appender>-->

  <appender name="ASYNCSTDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </appender>

  <logger name="play" level="INFO" />
  <logger name="application" level="DEBUG" />
  <logger name="com.example.notifications" LEVEL="TRACE" />




  <!-- Off these ones as they are annoying, and anyway we manage configuration ourselves -->
  <logger name="com.avaje.ebean.config.PropertyMapLoader" level="OFF" />
  <logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.XmlConfigLoader" level="OFF" />
  <logger name="com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.lib.BackgroundThread" level="OFF" />
  <logger name="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript" level="OFF" />

  <root level="WARN">
    <!--<appender-ref ref="ASYNCFILE" />-->
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNCSTDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

I do not see any log messages from inside my actors, unless I use **log.error**, why is that?

I set the level to TRACE for com.example.notifications

Am I correct in understanding that whenever I use a logger, it will use the logger defined in logback that matches the package name? i.e. com.example.notification will be used to lookup the logger in my logback.xml and use the LEVEL defined there?

Answer (score 2):

You need to read this [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/logging.html#slf4j) on how to enable `slf4j` in `akka`.

In summary,

add to `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.5.19",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3"
)
```

add to `application.conf`

```
akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
  logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
}
```

> You need to enable the Slf4jLogger in the loggers element in the
>   configuration. Here you can also define the log level of the event
>   bus. More fine grained log levels can be defined in the configuration
>   of the SLF4J backend (e.g. logback.xml). You should also define
>   akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter in the logging-filter
>   configuration property. It will filter the log events using the
>   backend configuration (e.g. logback.xml) before they are published to
>   the event bus.

Comment: just to make sure, is this the best practise? I was reading that logging incorrectly in akka can really slow down performance.  thanks!

Comment: This is the way to enable logging in akka. Indeed, having a lot of logging can have impact on the system. Because of this you have control over level and logging-filter to limit the amount of log events in the event bus. In production environments, it's recommended to have small amount of logs.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your project depends on [`"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j"`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-slf4j) and [`"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic"`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic). Otherwise akka might use a logger implentation other than logback.

If that does not solve your issue, try to explicitly use the logger of your ActorSystem:

```
system.log.debug("starting main supervisor actor Iot")
```